# Automated login to Stackoverflow

Tags: php, authentication

I get quite annoyed by logging in to SO sometimes and i'd like to do it by just calling a PHP file. I tried doing so by sending a post request like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&amp;returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f';
$data = array('email' => 'mymail@gmail.com', 'password' => 'mypasswort');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
?>
```

I also tried including more values like `ssrc` and `fkey` but i just shows the SO mainpage after submitting. It even stays at localhost (or wherever the script is running). If i enter a wrong password it marks it as incorrect -  so it has to work at lest in some way (the data verification)...

Comment: Is there csrf protection for login page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send post data:

```
isSignup:false
isLogin:true
isPassword:false
isAddLogin:false
hasCaptcha:false
fkey:922b6dc5a5a375283c44e298246d7763
ssrc:head
email:asd
password:
submitbutton:Log in
oauthversion:
oauthserver:
openidusername:
openididentifier:
```

You should send first **GET** request and parse `fkey` from result page (this is [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection).
`fkey` you should send with **POST** request with post data which I show you.

Simple example:

```php
<?php

$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head';
$data = array(
    'email' => 'mail@email.z',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'isSignup' => false,
    'isLogin' => true,
    'isPassword' => false,
    'isAddLogin' => false,
    'hasCaptcha' => false,
    'fkey' => '',
    'ssrc' => 'head',
    'submitbutton' => 'Log in',
    'oauthversion' => '',
    'oauthserver' => '',
    'openidusername' => '',
    'openididentifier' => ''
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method' => 'GET',
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

preg_match('~name\=\"fkey\"\svalue=\"([\w]+)\"~', $result, $matches);

$data['fkey'] = $matches[1];

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

But I recommend for you use [SO API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and you willn't have any problems

If you will have problem, write

Comment: i added the missing values but i get the same result :C i also read through the SO api but it looks like its for handling actions on specific posts and users...

Comment: Do you parse form before send request? `fkey` - it's dynamic value

Comment: all i do is what i wrote in my question... thats the whole script being executed